# swaping strings inside of a list using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, swap, shift

I have a list that contains file names like f1, f2, f3,...,f6. my

program needs to output a list with file names appearing in

random order such as f4,f1,f6,f2,f3,f5.
I want to swap or shift string correctly inside a list I have a list of

size 6 named `fileName` already containing 6 different file names I

am swapping file names inside of a list fileName as follows and `fil`

is also a string for remembering current string or file name.

```
temp =-1;
foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls) // run loop untill every control inside tablelayoutpanel1.Controls is check or read
{

Button btns = control as Button;                    // btn sotre the 

current button in table.contr 
if (btns != null)                                   // check btn got a button from 

the panel then
{
    temp++;
    int randomNumber = 0; 

    randomNumber = theArray[temp];   //this pic the random number from 0 index then 1 so on theArray already contains random number from 0 to 5 without any repitition and also tested
    fil = fileName[randomNumber];  //fil for holding string

    fileName[temp] = fileName[randomNumber]; // at filname[0] 

swap or shift filename[randomNumber] random are between 0 to 

5 and without repitition 
    fileName[randomNumber] = fil; // this line isnt even necessary 

but to be safe i wrot
    btns.BackgroundImage =  images[randomNumber];    // change 

btn image to current random image
    copyImages.Add(images[randomNumber]);

    btns.BackgroundImage = null;  // i purposely doing this :)


}
```

Using that code I am able to swap string but I cant swap them

correctly as it only run for 6 times so it should swap 6 strings

(each with different name) inside the list on 6 different location

inside the list `fileName` but its not happening some strings are

showing twice or thrice, hoping someone can point out what I am

doing wrong and theres no index out of range or exception error

I tested it for like hundred time please help thanks and any idea

suggestion or piece of code will be helpful and `fil` just storing the string at the location of fileName[temp] :) and `temp` just going from 0 to 5 in a loop
i dont want to shuffle them i just want to swap them according to given index which i am doing in my code but cant to it properly `theArray` already contains the suffle index i just want to assign the `fileName[0]` index to `theArray[temp]` i can send you my proj if you want to have a look just send me hi to my id which show in my profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given you have a List of length 6 and an int[6] containing 0 to five in random order

```
List<String> newList = newList<String>();
foreach(int position in theArray)
{
   newList.Add(filename[pos]);
}
filename.Clear();
fileName.AddRange(newList);
```

would be one way.
or you could simply do filename = newList and not bother with the `Clear` and `AddRange`.

Answer (score 0):

You stored the wrong String in your temporary variable.

```
fil = fileName[temp];  // index changed here
fileName[temp] = fileName[randomNumber];
fileName[randomNumber] = fil;
```

Comment: fil just storing the string at the location of fileName[temp] :) and temp just going from 0 to 5 in a loop

Comment: its not storing anything

Comment: I mean in order to swap elements you typically have to store one of them in a temporary variable. You assign the first of the elements to be swapped to the temporary (1st line), assign the first element to become the second element (2nd line) and lastly the second element to become the former first element which is stored in the temporary (3rd line). Now I thought fil is your temporary, then you would have got the right side of the first assignment (1st line above) wrong. In your code, after the second of the cited lines, `fil == fileName[temp] == fileName[randomNumber]`, hence the duplicates.

Comment: Well, but in your code fil does not store fileName[temp] but fileName[randomNumber].

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to shuffle elements in an array. Basicly you go through the array from one end to the middle, swapping each element with one selected at random. Since each swap operation results in two elements being randomly placed, when we reach the middle, the whole array is shuffled.

```
void Main()
{
    var arr = new string[] {"a","b","c"};
    Shuffle(arr);
    // arr is now shuffled
}

public static void Shuffle<T>(T[] arr)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = arr.Length; i > arr.Length / 2; i--)
    {
        Swap(arr, r.Next(i), i -1);
    }
}

private static void Swap<T>(T[] arr, int first, int second)
{
    T temp = arr[first];
    arr[first] = arr[second];
    arr[second] = temp;
}
```

Comment: i dont want to shuffle them i just want to swap them according to given index which i am doing in my code but cant to it properly `theArray` already contains the suffle index i just want to assign the `fileName[0]` index to `theArray[temp]` i can send you my proj if you want to have a look just send me hi to my id which show in my profile